# How tocheck if request uri contains array member

Tags: php, arrays, url

I have a basic url structure where items appear based on their create year.  So url.com/2012 or url.com/2011

I have created an array: `$year_array = range(2013, 2000);`

No I need to check that against the current request uri:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $year_array) !== false)
```

this does not work, but I am not sure why.  I am not a php expert.  Just learning...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array)

Try

```
$uri_parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (count($uri_parts) && in_array($uri_parts[0], $year_array)) {
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could name your parameter in the url, so something like

`url.com?year=2011`

unless of course you're using `modrewrite`

Then you could get the year from the url

`$year = $_GET['year']`;

Then use the php function [in_array](http://uk.php.net/in_array) to see if that year is in your `$year_array`

```
if (in_array($year, $year_array)) {
    //Do your thing
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you edited it to 'could' ;)... mod_rewrite is assuming an Apache environment, there's no reason not to parse the REQUEST_URI directly.

Comment: I agree, it was a little presumptuous haha. I just went for the simplest most transparent answer I could :)